# HTML5 Javascript paint brush

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, brush

I need to create a opacity brush clean and smooth.

This is one drawing line example what i need: [image]

Second picture what i get:
[image]

While i move cursor faster, i get little less circles in the drawing line

```js
    var el = document.getElementById('c');
    var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
    ctx.lineJoin = "round"
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000"; 
    ctx.globalAlpha = "0.2"; 
    ctx.lineWidth = 30; 
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

    var isDrawing, lastPoint;

    el.onmousedown = function(e) {
        isDrawing = true;
        lastPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
    };

    el.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (!isDrawing) return;

        var currentPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        ctx.lineTo(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

        lastPoint = currentPoint;
    };

    el.onmouseup = function() {
        isDrawing = false;
    };

    function clearit() {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, 1000, 1000);
    }
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<input type="button" id="clear-btn" value="Clear it" onclick="clearit()">
```

Comment: Maybe you should draw the line only when you release the mouse button. Take the `mousedown` as a starting point and the `mouseup` as an ending point.

Comment: i cannot because, i need to see what i drawing in real time

Comment: Ok. That makes everything more complex. I think you need to use double buffering then (to clear the line on every `mousemove` and draw it at the next position). On every `mousedown`, record the starting point of the line, save the canvas data, then, on every `mousemove`, clear the canvas, load the previous canvas data, draw a line between the starting point and the actual position, and stop the drawing on `mouseup`. (sorry I don't have time to write code yet, but that's how it works)

Comment: I think the problem is in how alpha composites are calculated: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377666/adding-color-components-with-transparency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that in mousemove you are starting and closing lots of paths, so the opacity of the line is overloading.

If you add:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(250,250);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

you can see that the effect is removed.

A partial solution (you can't see what you are drawing) is this:

```
 el.onmousedown = function(e) {
        isDrawing = true;
        lastPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    };

    el.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (!isDrawing) return;

        var currentPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };      
        ctx.lineTo(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        lastPoint = currentPoint;
    };

    el.onmouseup = function() {
        isDrawing = false;
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    };
```

Now we begin the path with mousedown, 'draw' the path in mousemove, and stroke the path with mouseup. I'm not sure about the 'closePath()' effect, but the inner circles disappear.

Comment: with this exmaple, you cannot see it real time

Comment: its like real painting - you have to guess, so you take shorter strokes.

Comment: Have you tried using SVG instead? This would allow you to place temporary points while drawing, and then remove them in order to place the desired line.

Comment: i need raster graphic not vector :) svg = vector, yes ? :/

Answer (score 0):

There is also a neat work around using two canvases:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas {
border:1px solid #c3c3c3;
}
</style>

</head>   
<body>   
<canvas id="cv1" width="400" height="300">    
</canvas>
<canvas id="cv2" width="400" height="300">
</canvas>
<hr>
<button onclick='merge();'>Merge</button>
<script>
var el1 = document.getElementById('cv1');
var el2 = document.getElementById('cv2');
    var ctx1 = el1.getContext('2d');
    var ctx2 = el2.getContext('2d');
    ctx1.lineJoin = "round"
    ctx1.strokeStyle = "#00FF00"; 
    ctx1.globalAlpha = "0.2"; 
    ctx1.lineWidth = 30; 
    ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    var isDrawing, lastPoint;
el1.onmousedown = function(e) {
        isDrawing = true;
        lastPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
    };  
    el1.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (!isDrawing) return;
        var currentPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
        ctx1.beginPath();
        ctx1.moveTo(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        ctx1.lineTo(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        ctx1.closePath();
        ctx1.stroke();
        lastPoint = currentPoint;
    };
    el1.onmouseup = function() {
        isDrawing = false;
    };
function merge() {
ctx2.putImageData(ctx1.getImageData(0,0,400,300),0,0);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This allows you to draw on one canvas, but if you don't like what you have done, you can reverse it.